# Which assert to use?

Tags: java

AFAIK, there are three common types of Asserts people use in Java viz.,

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/util/Assert.html
- http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Can you tell me the correct usage for each of the paradigm?

Comment: It is already given in the links you have provided...

Comment: @om39a:  I had gone through springframework assert documentation and it is not clear what is meant by "Mainly for internal use within the framework".  Is this meant only for Spring Framework developer?  There is also a reference to jakarta commons lang.  Can you tell me if the first link refers to jakarta commons lang?  The third option is a little obvious but just included it here for completeness.

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan Yes, it means that it's mainly for Spring developers, not Spring users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 are *runtime* assertions. They are usually used to make sure that you are getting only values that you expect to get.

Option 1 is more common since it's a Java language feature. If you type `assert` into your code in an IDE, it will highlight it because it is a Java keyword (not part of the Jakarta library).

Option 2 is Spring-specific; looking at the docs that you linked to, it says that following:

> Mainly for internal use within the framework; consider Jakarta's Commons Lang >= 2.0 for a more comprehensive suite of assertion utilities.

Option 3 is used almost exclusively for jUnit testing. They ensure that your tests are outputting the values that you expect your code to produce.

Most likely, you will use Option 1 in the code that you write. As the docs say, you probably will never use Option 2. You will only use Option 3 if you write jUnit tests.